# How to run a service in the background within an existing solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, configuration, windows-services

I have a built a windows service and the service works well when I run it, however to get it to run I am having to set it to run as the startup project and I dont want to do that because it exists within the main solution and I want to run the main solution and get the windows service to run in the background. How do I configure the service to run in the background within my main solution. I already added the install file and the service is working

Comment: please share your code so I can help you

Comment: What you're asking is not really possible. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-debug-windows-service-applications